# Significato di "invidia nera"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> La sera del ventitré agosto i bordanti boccheggiano sul tetto e i ragazzi sono in strada: Lena è rimasta sola nell’appartamento. Dopo l’ennesimo vavattenne abbascio ca te piglio pe’ ’ssi quattro pirci ca te ’n coccia uocca fràceta zoccola ch’anzi tu, Lena, che non è il tipo da mettersi a litigare con una turba di befane sudate, sul tetto non c’è salita piú, e passa il tempo in casa, a pensare alle montagne sue, ascoltando la musica del grammofono a tutto volume e suscitando l’**invidia nera** di chi il grammofono non ce l’ha e non ce l’avrà mai – cioè praticamente di tutti.

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "invidia nera" che appare in questo brano. Potreste spiegarmelo? Ho cercato alla voce "invidia" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'aggettivo "nera" serve in questo caso a rafforzare, diciamo con una nota di colore, il sentimento dell'invidia. Il nero viene associato a cose buie, oscure, negative; quindi l'invidia è *nera* quando rabbuia completamente lo stato d'animo di chi la prova.

Si usa anche in locuzioni come *rabbia nera* o *fame nera*.

Secondo me è possibile parlare in questo caso di una *[sinestesia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinestesia_(figura_retorica))* in quanto appunto, i sentimenti non hanno colori visibili.

Comment: Tuttavia, da una ricerca su Google, mi è sembrato capire che si tratta di un'espressione che si usa abbastanza. Si trova persino in alcuni testi del Settecento:

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=DeNfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP244&lpg=PP244&dq=%22invidia+nera%22&source=bl&ots=XHTd2vsFMc&sig=ACfU3U0OdrQ_M7n5d82zuKURyPZbPIo_Uw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0wMzW68_gAhXp2OAKHYOCDkI4ChDoAQgdMAI#v=onepage&q=%22invidia%20nera%22&f=false, https://books.google.es/books?id=4ejibRJisZYC&pg=PA287&lpg=PA287&dq=%22invidia+nera%22&source=bl&ots=dH8SMVnH-s&sig=ACfU3U3dgfvjSXxe0KA5av2z7ijpX3I89Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0wMzW68_gAhXp2OAKHYOCDkI4ChDoAQgfMAM#v=onepage&q=%22invidia%20nera%22&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.es/books?id=I-NfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP364&lpg=PP364&dq=%22invidia+nera%22&source=bl&ots=gJ5wbcn4D9&sig=ACfU3U2K3Z_zDGZiRxdvlZ2kinx7zA6sEA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0wMzW68_gAhXp2OAKHYOCDkI4ChDoAQghMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22invidia%20nera%22&f=false

Comment: Adesso ho visto in [questo articolo de *La Crusca per voi*](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://nencioni.sns.it/fileadmin/template/allegati/QuesitiRisposte/2001_23/2001_23_Risposta_7.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiLnfmb9s_gAhUBzoUKHXAVBDcQFjACegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw03ajU1f9VyL16aEMV7AgZe) che la sinestesia è "un fenomeno non solo dello 
scrivere colto e artistico, ma anche dell’uso comune". In questo articolo si trovano esempi come "voce chiara", "sorriso amaro", "prezzi salati", ecc.

Comment: @charo mi ricordo che qualche anno fa - a proposito di una vittoria della Ferrari  - un giornale ha titolato "L'urlo rosso" e un lettore chiese come fosse possibile per un urlo essere "rosso" . La risposta del giornalista è stata: sì, è possibile. Si chiama sinestesia :)